# PHP-Firebird (ibase_connect = CHARACTER SET iso-8859-1 is not defined)

Tags: php, firebird, firebird2.5

im new about firebird. I'm trying to connect between php and firebird. This is the code :

```
$host='192.168.12.1:D:/DB/ALFABETA.FDB';
$username='john.doe';
$password='123456789';
$database='ALFABETA';

$dbh=ibase_connect($host,$username,$password) or die (ibase_errmsg());

$sth=  ibase_query($dbh) or die (ibase_errmsg());
```

But after i run the code in browser, the warning statement is coming up. Help. What i should do ?

***Warning Statement***

> Warning: ibase_connect(): bad parameters on attach or create database
>   CHARACTER SET iso-8859-1 is not defined in
>   /var/www/fortrainingcrud/connect_db.php on line 7 bad parameters on
>   attach or create database CHARACTER SET iso-8859-1 is not defined

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the answer ! Here it is :

1. In php.ini, i add `extension=php_interbase.dll`
2. **Restart the Apache service**
3. The code that i've write before, works well

Comment: If this was the problem, wouldn't you get **Call to undefined function ibase_connect()**? How could `ibase_connect()` run if the extension was not loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting the connection charset yet you get an error about it. That suggests that PHP is taking the value from somewhere else and the first candidate is the `ibase.default_charset` directive. You can see its current value with `var_dump(ini_get('ibase.default_charset'));` or simply by running `phpinfo()`.

You can either change the directive yourself or, even better, specify the encoding at `ibase_connect()` so your code doesn't break randomly depending on server configuration.

As about `iso-8859-1`, it seems the appropriate syntax for Firebird is `ISO8859_1` (assuming you really want that encoding).